# Syntax question: Why is it necessary to define a function as async in JS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, syntax

It's a simple question. We have the `await` keyword which allows the function execution to return a result before continuing. Of course you can use promises in the same way, but I'm specifically interested in async in this question.

An async function would appear in the following context.

```js
const funcA = async newValue => {
    await connection.query(`UPDATE t SET field = ?`, [newValue])
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

    const valueA = await connection.query(`SELECT t.field FROM t LIMIT 1`)
    .then(([results, fields]) => (results?.[0] ?? null))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));

    console.log(valueA.field);
};

funcA("test");
```

A similar method of executing this without async would be

```js
const funcA = newValue => {
    connection.query(`UPDATE t SET field = ?`, [newValue])
    .then(() => connection.query(`SELECT t.field FROM t LIMIT 1`))
    .then(([results, fields]) => (results?.[0] ?? null));
    .then(valueA => console.log(valueA.field))
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

funcA("test");
```

Now ignoring the practicality of this example code, and just focusing on the functionality, why do we need to use the `async` keyword before defining the function at all? Why not allow `await` in every function. The second example could have the `async` keyword but it wouldn't work any differently because promises work the same in both contexts. Couldn't we just eliminate the `async` keyword entirely?

I'm certain I must be missing something here but I don't know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: The whole point of `async` and `await` was to get away from having to manually and explicitly create `.then()` callback chains. It's far clearer to use `async` and `await`, and much less error-prone.

Comment: @Pointy I know, but the question is, why do you need the syntax for async. Why not just default every function to async? And have `await` do all the work.

Comment: And it would be impossible to allow `await` in every function, because the calling environment has to know that the call to an `async` function must expect the way the function will work. Understand that an `async` function can include inside its code many `await` statements, and the calling environment has to deal with that.

Comment: because not every function *is* asynchronous, and it would be pointless for all function calls to behave as if a Promise is returned.

Comment: @Pointy explain. Why does it matter whether the function is asynchronous? If an `await` isn't defined within the function, then as far as I can see the functionality is identical to a normal function.

Comment: Because of the Promise architecture. If you call `await` inside a function, it returns a Promise. And no, the functionality is most definitely not identical; why would the syntax exist if it were?

Comment: @Pointy Okay I got it! You're right. I tested it with `const test = async () => { let t = await "test"; return t; } const test2 = () => { let t = "test"; return t };` If you wanna add it as an answer, I think it could be helpful to other people in the future.

Comment: An `async` function pretty much works as a generator. An `await` on an `async` function will handle the sequence of `await` calls from inside the function, which essentially work like `yield` with a Promise. When the function finishes, the calling environment knows that the generator iteration is finished and the calling environment can proceed.

Comment: I would add an answer if I thought I could really explain it with technical accuracy; mostly I've just gotten used to it.

Comment: To @Pointy's point: I like writing `Math.log(x) / Math.log(b)`. I do not like the idea of having to write `Promise.all([Math.log(x), Math.log(b)]).then((lx, lb) => lx / lb)`. Even the equivalent `await Math.log(x) / await Math.log(b)` is inconvenient. Not every function needs to return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK this should not be taken as an authoritative answer. More like a folk tradition answer.

When code calls a function the way our grandparents called functions:

```
let x = f();
```

the function is invoked, it does what it does, and its return value is assigned to x.

Now let's talk about an `async` function. Such functions are intended to help deal with the problem of sequencing calls to asynchronous operations. Formerly, that required constructing chains of `.then()` and callbacks, and `.catch()` for exceptions. That *works*, but it's confusing and error-prone.

What `async` and `await` provide is an abstraction around handling that kind of Promise sequence of operations. Underneath, the Promise mechanism still does the same thing. A way to think about it (that is not entirely accurate) is that the `await` operator turns the code that follows it into a `.then()` callback for you.

Because a single `async` function may have many `await` calls internally, when it is called with `await` from some context, there we have to handle the fact that the single call may return Promise after Promise:

```
const af = async function() {
    let val = await a();
    val = await b(val);
    val = await c(val);
    return val;
}
```

Each `await` inside the `async` function will return a Promise. But consider calling `af`:

```
    let foo = await af();
```

To evaluate that, the three Promise objects returned from the `await` expressions within the function must *all* complete, one after the other, before the code in the calling context can move on to the subsequent statements.

OK, now, if your hair is not on fire yet, it is possible to `await` anything you want:

```
let d = await Date.now();
```

That works fine. The value of `d` will be a Promise, because if the expression that's awaited isn't a Promise you effectively get

```
let d = Promise.resolve().then(_ => Date.now());
```

Of course `d` will still be a Promise, and that's kind-of a mess.

Also, you can call an `async` function without `await` and that's fine, as long as you realize that you're getting a Promise back.

Because this stuff is really hard to explain in precise mechanical detail, to me it's better to be in the habit of sticking with `async` and `await` and following the rules. Don't mix `.then()` code into the mix unless you really need to. It's easy to forget to return the result of a Promise `.then()` chain. With `async` and `await`, all you have to worry about is keeping track of the functions you're calling that are either explicitly `async` or that you know will return Promise objects (because `await` will work fine in that case too).

Comment: Thanks this clears it up. The most important aspect to me is that the async function returns a promise while the normal function doesn't. Makes complete sense.

Comment: A nitpick or two: `await` never returns a `Promise`; in fact, it does the opposite, it _unpacks_ a promise, if its argument is one (and throws an exception, if the promise was rejected). After `let d = await Date.now();`, `d` will _not_ be a promise, it will be a `Date` object. It is the `return` in an `async` function that packs the return value back up into a promise so we can stay in `async`-land.

Comment: @Amadan yes please feel free to edit, like I said, this answer was not intended to be an authoritative report on how this stuff works.